# What handler/method is called during persistent cookie login?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a project that is configured with ASP.NET Identity and is using the Local Account option. I have modified the context to collect additional data and everything is working great.  One such field is used to store the users LastLoginDate which is being set within the Login's Post ActionResult.

The problem is that after a user has selected the "Remember Me" option none of the usual handlers or methods are being hit. I've stepped through trying to find them and couldn't so I assume that there's a method I need to override.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using Local Account OWIN will create a cookie called .AspNet.ApplicationCookie when a user is logged in. 
This cookie will be stored in the browser.
The cookie will be set to expire when browser session ends or by default to 14 days from log in if the user select the "Remember Me" option.
If the cookie is present in the browser and not expired then the user is logged in and doesn't have to log in. I suppose this is what you are seeing, i.e. that the user doesn't log in at all because the default is 14 days and sliding expiration, meaning that a user that choose the "remember me" and use the site at least once each 14 days will stay logged in.

You can change the defaults by adding options to the CookieAuthenicationOptions that are initialized in Startup.Auth.cs. I.e. to set the expiry on the cookie to a week and not use sliding expiry you would do this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
      ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0),
      SlidingExpiration = false
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, is very helpful. So while they have the cookie there is no server-side method called when they visit, correct?  So because of this, there is no way to know when, or how often, a user visits the site when they have the cookie.  Is this correct?  Thanks.

Comment: You could choose to not allow the "remember me" option. Then the user will have to log in each time he restart his browser completely.Regular action methods are of course always called and you could do checks here. If you don't want to remove "remember me" option you could make a check in all action methods to see who is calling your methods. E.g. you could override OnActionExecuting and check if the user is authenticated and then who it is.